# On click, slide background color from one button to another

Tags: jquery, css

I have two buttons like this:

[image]

The active state is the white background so when the second button is clicked, I want the white background to slide from the left to the right, making the second button white and the first blue. Then reverse the effect on clicking the first button. Is that possible?

Almost like a toggle button effect but the background slides from one to another.

At the moment it's looking a bit odd!

```js
  // Downloads page
  $(".download-tab").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var item = $(this).data('number');
   $('.download-tab[data-number="' + item + '"]').addClass("download-active");
   $('.downloads[data-number="' + item + '"]').show().siblings(".downloads").hide();
  });
```

```css
.download-tab {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:5px 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
 border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
 border:solid 3px blue;
 text-align: center;
 margin-right:-7px;
 background-color:blue;
 color:white;
 font-size:13px;
 min-width:150px;
}

.download-active {
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 /* Old browsers */
 background: linear-gradient(to left, white 50%, blue 50%);
 background-size: 200% 100%;
 background-position:right bottom;
}

.download-active:active,
.download-active:focus {
    background-position:left bottom;
}

#download-button-1 {
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px!important;
 border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px!important;
 background-color:white;
 color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="download-button-1" class="download-tab" href="#" data-number="<?php echo $count; ?>">Button 1</a>
                    <a id="download-button-<?php echo $count; ?>" class="download-tab" href="#" data-number="<?php echo $count; ?>">Button 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create CSS class with the height:0 rule, and toggle that class with JS:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("box");
function slide() {
elem.classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

CSS

```
.box {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
overflow: hidden;
background: orange;
margin: 0 auto;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.hide {
height: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="slide();">Slide Toggle</button>
<div id="box" class="box">Show / Hide</div>
```